# Why am I getting "Request is missing required authentication credential" when making POST request to YouTube API v3 with Python Requests module?

Tags: python, python-requests, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am downloading YouTube comments with Python by making POST requests with the Requests module to

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads`.

However, even though I am supplying an API key, I am getting the following error message:

`{'error': {'code': 401, 'message': 'Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.', 'errors': [{'message': 'Login Required.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'required', 'location': 'Authorization', 'locationType': 'header'}], 'status': 'UNAUTHENTICATED'}}`.

From what I can gather, this (and the link) is saying that I need an OAuth 2 token, but I don't feel like that is applicable to the kind of function I am trying to carry out.

Here is the code I am using to make the request:

```
import requests

YOUTUBE_COMMENTS_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads'
params = {
            'part': 'snippet,replies',
            'maxResults': 100,
            'videoId': video_id,
            'textFormat': 'plainText',
            'key': ******
        }
        
headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
        }
data = requests.post(self.YOUTUBE_COMMENTS_URL, params=params, headers=headers)
results = data.json()
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error message?

Comment: Are you sure those are supposed to be `params`, instead of `data`?

Comment: Indeed is sufficient to have an OAuth token, but is not necessary, since that API call will work OK with only a valid `key`. Can you assure yourself that `key` is not an empty string? Note also that the maximum value allowed for `maxResults` is 50.

Comment: @JohnGordon You might be right actually. Do you know what I would have to change with regards to the info that I am passing if I change it to `data`?

Comment: @stvar I am sure that it is not anempty string - I get the same error if I pass it explicitly with the key. Thanks for the tip about the `maxResults`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry, Charlie, I should have noticed the problem earlier.)

The problem with your code is as follows: since you're invoking the HTTP `POST` method on the URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads`,

it means that you really are invoking the [`CommentThreads.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert) API endpoint, and not [`CommentThreads.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list).

This explains why the API complains about not receiving an OAuth token, since `CommentThreads.insert` do require such kind of [authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert#auth).

Do notice that the two endpoints have the same URL, yet what differentiates one from the other is the HTTP method that invoked each:

- [`GET`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#http-request) for `CommentThreads.list`, and
- [`POST`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert#http-request) for `CommentThreads.insert`.

Therefore, to fix your code you'll have to have something like:

```
data = requests.get(
    YOUTUBE_COMMENTS_URL,
    params = params,
    headers = headers
)
```

Note also that passing `params` is simply OK (it's not necessary to pass the request's parameters to `data`).